# do I place a comma before "well"?

Tags: commas

I'm writing a novel and still getting use to rules for commas. In my novel I have this:

"Well, she better not eat any of my customers,or I’ll be having cougar tonight."

does this comma before the *well* look correct? I'm confused because I thought you could only have commas between independent clauses but at the same time it feels right.

Comment: Third pedantic point: it should be "she **had** better", although if it's dialogue, I suppose you could intentionally be having your character speak ungrammatically.

Answer (score 2):

In this sentence "well" is serving as an interjection, so it is proper to set it off with a comma.

Comment: But the comma should be after "well", not before it.